# Loop over objects in an environment returned by getSymbols

Tags: r, quantmod

I have about 2000 or so stock tickers that I loaded into R using:

```
companyList <- read.csv("~/Downloads/companylist.csv")
#saved all 2000 symbols inside the variable "ticker"
ticker <- as.vector(as.character(companyList[1:2000, 'Symbol']))
StockData <- new.env()
data <- getSymbols(ticker, env = stockData)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to run calculations on each stocks data without doing manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eapply`:

```
 eapply(stockData, FUN=calcul)
```

Comment: Anyway to put this into an if statement to check each stocks results?

Comment: the result is just a named list with your stock variables.